# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_datasets.text' has no attribute 'YelpPolarityReviews'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to download a TensorFlow dataset [yelp polarity reviews](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/yelp_polarity_reviews)

In order to do this I am doing the following command:

```
tfds.text.YelpPolarityReviews
```

But this return the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_datasets.text' has no attribute
> 'YelpPolarityReviews'

After this I triyed to download the hole datasets of the following way:

```
import tensorflow_datasets.download.DownloadManager as dl_manager
train_dir = dl_manager.download_and_extract('https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-nlp/yelp_review_polarity_csv.tgz')
```

But this doesn't work and I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets.download'

The question is how can I download that dataset in order to use it with TensorFlow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset is yelp_polarity_reviews, you **have to add the underscore and make sure everything is in small**. Can you try this out and see if it works?

```
!pip install tensorflow-datasets
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
data = tfds.load('yelp_polarity_reviews', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
```

Comment: In the doc the codes is the code that I wrote, but when your code dosen't work too.

Comment: I added the code now, it's from a kaggle notebook, should work, https://www.kaggle.com/anasofiauzsoy/yelp-review-sentiment-analysis-tensorflow-tfds

Comment: Oh well, have you installed everything in conda?

Comment: I have all instaled